Introductory clause and preposition
I'm reading a draft of a paper and the following clause makes me feel uncomfortable:

A crucial point to note here is that with the proposed service, A is the equivalent of only from x% to y% of the price of B

I'm not sure if "...is that with..." is correct, then I think it can be rephrased as

Crucially, A with the proposed service is the equivalent...

Additionally, I'm not sure neither if "...the equivalent of only from x% to y% of.." is correct, but I don't know any replacement.

Perhaps clearer is 'A crucial point to note here is that with the proposed service, the price of A will/should be only x-y%  the price of B.'

"with the proposed service" describes the whole circumstance, not just A. So the original sentence is correct.
